# ArcGIS Insights - SQL Filter Edit Date by today

Tags: sql, insights-for-arcgis

I'd like to setup a filter on a ArcGIS Insights table were EditDate = Today

I'm currently using a 24 hour filter (DATEDIF(EditDate, NOW(), "H")<=24) but would prefer a current day filter e.g. between 12am and 11.59pm on current day

Comment: And what is holding you back from doing so? (aka: Please add some more details on what you tried and where you struggle)

Comment: More detail added